# ssh expect script doesn't recognize connect string

Tags: ssh

I tried my hand at an expect script that's supposed to copy an ssh public key up to a remote server and copy it into place so that you'll be able to ssh into it wihout having to enter in a password next time.

I'm trying to allow for a host connecting for the first time to expect the complaint about an unrecognized host key:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set PUB "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
spawn scp $PUB openplatform@100.114.114.106:
expect {
 "(Are you sure you want to continue connecting yes/no)?" { send "yes\r"; exp_continue }
  password:                                                {send secret!\r; exp_continue}
  }
expect "password: "
send "secret!\r"
```

This is what happens when I actually run the script:

```
#./bin/ssh-login.ssh
spawn scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub openplatform@100.114.114.106:
spawn ssh openplatform@100.114.116.106 /bin/mkdir .ssh && /bin/chmod 700 .ssh && /bin/cat id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys && /bin/chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
The authenticity of host '100.114.116.106 (100.114.116.106)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 3b:04:73:25:24:f3:aa:99:75:a7:98:62:5d:dd:1b:38.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? secret!
Please type 'yes' or 'no':
```

Basically the problem is that the line I'm trying to setup to expect the "Are you sure you want to continue connecting yes/no" string is not being recognized by the script.

Any suggestions on how I can improve that so that those lines match?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your script - the opening bracket on the "Are you sure..." line should be before the "yes/no", not at the start.  The fixed version:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set PUB "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
spawn scp $PUB openplatform@100.114.114.106:
expect {
 "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" { send "yes\r"; exp_continue }
  password:                                                {send secret!\r; exp_continue}
  }
expect "password: "
send "secret!\r"
```

...works fine for me